# MediaExtractor.advance() - End of stream signalled earlier than expected

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I have problem with end of stream signalled earlier than expected (way before file ends) by the `advance()` method of `MediaExtractor` class. According to Google reference the [advance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html#advance()) method could work wrong when using a local file (and this is my case - `filePath` ponits to a local file):

> When extracting a local file, the behaviors of advance() and
>   readSampleData(ByteBuffer, int) are undefined in presence of
>   concurrent writes to the same local file:

Unfortunately there is no single word about using `MediaExtractor` without `advance()` method. How to move to the next sample? If there is no way to do it then I'd like to know how to feed `inputBuffer` without using `MediaExtractor`.

A fragment of my code below:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) {

        try {
            codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.mp3.decoder");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(filePath);     //local file
            Log.i("filePath", String.valueOf(filePath));
            extractor.selectTrack(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
                // fill inputBuffer with valid data
                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer,0);

                if(extractor.advance) {

                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, sampleSize, 0, 0);


                } else {
                        // EOS
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    codec.stop();
                    codec.release();
                }


            }
// more callbacks

};


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my samples MediaExtractor worked correctly when I used another construction of statements. I did not check **EOS** with **extractor.advance()** like you. Try how other samples offer:

```
   int chunkSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);
   if (chunkSize < 0) {
        // End of stream -- send empty frame with EOS flag set.
        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, 0, 0L,
                MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
    } else {
        // No EOS -- continue
        long presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, chunkSize,
                presentationTimeUs, 0 /*flags*/);
        extractor.advance();
    }
```

BTW, the guide of [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) tells about such usage.
Fadden has MoviePlayer in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MoviePlayer.java) with MediaExtractor. But it feeds decoder without *MediaCodec.Callback*.

Comment: This works. Could you tell me then what does this mean `When extracting a local file, the behaviors of advance() and readSampleData(ByteBuffer, int) are undefined in presence of concurrent writes to the same local file`? According to this reference, your code should not work, but it actually works.

Comment: I was also confused when read this in developer guide. But i tried samples and their behavior was OK. So i just skipped this info :)